# Value of type 'Result<Any, AFError>' has no member 'value' JSON

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, response, xcode12

Does anyone knows how to solve this bug? By the way, I'm a beginner, be kind!

```
AF.request(URL_LOGIN, method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { (response) in
    
        if response.result.erro == nil {
            if let json = response.result.erro as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                if let email = json["user"] as? String {
                    self.userEmail = email
                }
                if let token = json["token"] as? String {
                    self.authToken = token
                }
            }
            self.isLoggedIn = true
            completion(true)
        } else {
            completion(false)
            debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6G3B.png)

Comment: You shouldn't use `self.isLoggedIn` as a boolean variable to check login status. Try to keep one global `UserModel` containing all the values that you need related to a user and check if it is nil to determine if user is logged in. Makes maintenance easier.

Comment: got it! it's being just a month that I'm into programming. I'm taking online classes without any mentor. It's challenging... 
But I'll take your advice. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! It is not a bug, it is a compile time error says that object of type `Result<Any, AFError>` has no such property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check your spelling, `erro` is pointless.

According to the error the value for `result` is `Result<Any, AFError>`, [`Result`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) is an enum with associated types and two cases: `success` and `failure`

The syntax must be something like

```
AF.request(URL_LOGIN, method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { (response) in

    switch response.result {
      case .success(let result):
        if let json = result as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
            if let email = json["user"] as? String {
                self.userEmail = email
            }
            if let token = json["token"] as? String {
                self.authToken = token
            }
        }
        self.isLoggedIn = true
        completion(true)
      case .failure(let error):
        completion(false)
        debugPrint(error)
    }
}
```

The logic is not very logic. I'm sure that `self.isLoggedIn` is not supposed to be `true` if `email` and `token` are invalid and should be set to `false` when an error occurs.

Comment: Fantastic! Worked!